# Support Library Froyo to Lollipop

Tags: android, android-support-library

How, Which and Where do I need to implement the support-libraries in order to get the app working on older android-versions.
What do I need to implement for a app running on Lollipop as well as on Froyo?

Comment: Download Android Studio, create new project and the wizard will do it for you.

Comment: Check the android distribution: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone   Froyo is 0.4%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting make sure you have the Android Support Library and Android Support Repository downloaded on the SDK Manager.

**Eclipse**

1. Create a directory named libs/ in the root of your project directory.
2. Copy the JAR file from your SDK installation to the libs/ folder.
3. In Eclipse right click the JAR and choose Build Path > Add to Build Path.

**Android Studio**

1. Open the build.gradle file in your application module. (Usually named app).
2. In the dependencies part add the following line:

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
   ```
3. Finally do a Gradle Sync

Comment: Thanks. I am working with eclipse. Do I need to include all the support-libraries existing? How do I use these libraries later inside the code? Is there something important to think about and look at while programming, so the app does not crash in older versions?

Comment: @newAndroid It is pretty simple. The JAR files represent each library. Once you add the library to the build path you can then use all the functions within that library. For your purpose you only need the appcompat-v7 library which can be obtained by downloading the Android Support Library in SDK manager.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And this includes the actionBar a.s.o? And after that I just import this library into the regarding class?

Comment: I assume you mean the new Toolbar API. Yes you do get that with the latest appcompat library.